Static files not being detected by the ALB
So, I have deployed an application in a Kubernetes environment (AWS EKS). It is a collection of various micro-applications exposed as services, each micro-service having three replica sets.
All the micro-applications are developed using Flask.
Each of these micro applications have their own static files and templates. All the required files needed for each micro-application are made available as a volume-mount from the AWS worker nodes (Please note that each pod only gets the particular files needed for the proper functioning of the particular micro-application that the pod is supposed to run).
The ingress is set up in the following way:
"/" leads to login-page service
"/home" leads to home-page service and so on.
Now, when I deploy the ALB, the login page seems to work fine, but whenever the home page is set to load, it is unable to find the static files required for the home page.
Upon further investigation, I noticed that the ALB is looking for the static resources for home-page inside the static folder of the login-page
--in login-page HTML template, url_for("static", filename="css/styleLogin.css") is returning xyz.com/static/css/styleLogin.css and is working fine
-- but in home-page HTML template, url_for("static", filename="css/styleHome.css") is returning xyz.com/static/css/styleHome.css [returns 404 not found]
